# Unable to open resource URI while running simple RESTFUL API using JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, glassfish

I am using netbeans IDE and GlasssFish server to run simple RESTFUL web application.
*Version Details : Apache NetBeans IDE 14 , Java 11, GlassFish Server 6.2.1*
Process I did followed

1. right click on project
2. click on run(it will build and deploy project on server)
3. right click on right-click on the appropriate HTTP methods, as shown in the following screenshot, and select Test Resource Uri.

This is the error I am getting:

[image: ResourceURLerror]

Glassfish Server Logs:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@1d0b497e in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Users\Pradeep\GlassFish_Server\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Users\Pradeep\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Users\Pradeep\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Pradeep\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties
  Running GlassFish Version: Eclipse GlassFish  6.2.1  (build master-b569-gad91414 2021-08-26T23:45:22+0000)|#]
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter|#]
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.|#]
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 163ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 105ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 81ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]|#]
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 7.0.1.Final|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 28ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 9ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]|#]
  Java security manager is disabled.|#]
  Entering Security Startup Service.|#]
  Loading policy provider org.glassfish.exousia.modules.locked.SimplePolicyProvider.|#]
  Security Service(s) started successfully.|#]
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080|#]
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181|#]
  Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848|#]
  Created virtual server server|#]
  Created virtual server __asadmin|#]
  Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web|#]
  Virtual server server loaded default web module |#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  Loading application [rest-chapter3-service] at [/rest-chapter3-service]|#]
  Loading application rest-chapter3-service done in 15,895 ms|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  WELD-000900: 4.0.2 (Final)|#]
  AS-CDI-00005|#]
  AS-CDI-00005|#]
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.|#]
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.|#]
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.ProcessAllAnnotatedTypes.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<?>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.|#]
  WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.ibm.jbatch.container.cdi.BatchProducerBean is deprecated from CDI 1.1!|#]
  Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.|#]
  WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.principal.rest.chapter.service.resources.JavaEE8Resource because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.ws.rs.core.Response not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.|#]
  WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.principal.rest.chapter.service.resources.RestAppConfig because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.ws.rs.core.Application not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.|#]
  WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.principal.rest.chapter.service.JAXRSConfiguration because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.ws.rs.core.Application not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.|#]
  Initializing Soteria 2.0.1 for context '/rest-chapter-3'|#]
  Loading application [rest-chapter-3-service] at [/rest-chapter-3]|#]
  Loading application rest-chapter-3-service done in 9,413 ms|#]
  Eclipse GlassFish  6.2.1  (master-b569-gad91414 2021-08-26T23:45:22+0000) startup time : Felix (54,621ms), startup services(28,203ms), total(82,824ms)|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 44ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]|#]
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@a20b94b as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@5cdf39b2.|#]
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181|#]
  Skipping registration of inhabitant for service reference [org.osgi.service.metatype.MetaTypeProvider] as the service object could not be obtained.|#]
  Grizzly Framework 3.0.0 started in: 72ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://DESKTOP-55BQ260:8686/jndi/rmi://DESKTOP-55BQ260:8686/jmxrmi|#]
  Initializing Mojarra 3.0.1 for context ''|#]
  Loading application [__admingui] at [/]|#]
  Loading application __admingui done in 11,930 ms|#]
  Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  visiting unvisited references|#]
  AS-CDI-00005|#]
  AS-CDI-00005|#]
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.|#]
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.|#]
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.ProcessAllAnnotatedTypes.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<?>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.|#]
  WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.ibm.jbatch.container.cdi.BatchProducerBean is deprecated from CDI 1.1!|#]
  WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.principal.rest.chapter.service.resources.JavaEE8Resource because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.ws.rs.core.Response not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.|#]
  WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.principal.rest.chapter.service.resources.RestAppConfig because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.ws.rs.core.Application not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.|#]
  WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.principal.rest.chapter.service.JAXRSConfiguration because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.ws.rs.core.Application not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.|#]
  Initializing Soteria 2.0.1 for context '/rest-chapter-3'|#]
  Loading application [rest-chapter-3-service] at [/rest-chapter-3]|#]
  rest-chapter-3-service was successfully deployed in 4,724 milliseconds.|#]
```

This is my code:

```
package com.principal.rest.chapter.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 *
 * @author Pradip
 */
@Path("departments")
public class DepartmentService {
    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

package com.principal.rest.chapter.service.resources;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
/**
 *
 * @author Pradeep
 */
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources") 
public class RestAppConfig extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
   Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
   resources.add(com.principal.rest.chapter.service.DepartmentService.class);
   return resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show any messages that are written to the Glassfish log when the URI is submitted. Also specify the version of NetBeans, Java and Glassfish that you are using.

Comment: @skomisa Apache NetBeans IDE 14 , Java 11, GlassFish Server 6.2.1.
Glassfish server console logs snippet :

Initializing Soteria 2.0.1 for context '/rest-chapter-3'|#]
Loading application [rest-chapter-3-service] at [/rest-chapter-3]|#]
rest-chapter-3-service was successfully deployed in 4,724 milliseconds.|#]

Comment: OK, but  please don't provide information about your question in the comments. Instead, directly update your question with the additional details.